# Display popup on click of a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a [website here](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/). When you click on the team tab, it will take you to the team section.

I am trying to create a popup here.The same pop up should work on clicking any of the points boxes:

[points box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge5yW.png)

Now I am getting the popup below the points box (see in the website)

Code involved (only related to team section to keep the problem relevant):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.counter col_fourth a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var block = _this.attr('href');
    $(".counter col_fourth").removeClass("active");
    _this.parent().addClass("active");
    $(".counter col_fourth").hide();
    $(block).fadeIn();
  });

  /**
   * Fade in the Popup
   */
  $('.counter col_fourth').on('click', function() {
    $('#popup').fadeIn();

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #808080;
  text-align: center;
}
/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */

/* Column Grids */

/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */

.team-leader-box {
  .col_half {
    width: 49%;
  }
  .col_third {
    width: 32%;
  }
  .col_fourth {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
  .col_fifth {
    width: 18.4%;
  }
  .col_sixth {
    width: 15%;
  }
  .col_three_fourth {
    width: 74.5%;
  }
  .col_twothird {
    width: 66%;
  }
  .col_half,
  .col_third,
  .col_twothird,
  .col_fourth,
  .col_three_fourth,
  .col_fifth {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .end {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
  }
  /* Column Grids End */
  .wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .counter {
    background-color: #808080;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .count-title {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .count-text {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .fa-2x {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: table;
    color: #4ad1e5;
  }
}
.counter.col_fourth {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main-section team" id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>team</h2>
    <h6>Take a closer look into our amazing team. We won’t bite.</h6>
    <div class="team-leader-block clearfix">
      <div class="team-leader-box">
        <div class="team-leader wow fadeInDown delay-03s">
          <div class="team-leader-shadow">
            <a href="#"></a>
          </div>
          <img src="img/team-leader-pic1.jpg" alt="">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-twitter"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-pinterest"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-google-plus"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
            <h2 class="timer count-title" id="count-number" data-to="50" data-speed="1500"></h2>
            <p class="count-text ">points</p>
            <p1>click to know</p1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="team-leader-box">
        <div class="team-leader  wow fadeInDown delay-06s">
          <div class="team-leader-shadow">
            <a href="#"></a>
          </div>
          <img src="img/team-leader-pic2.jpg" alt="">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-twitter"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-pinterest"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-google-plus"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
            <h2 class="timer count-title" id="count-number" data-to="30" data-speed="1500"></h2>
            <p class="count-text ">points</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="team-leader-box">
        <div class="team-leader wow fadeInDown delay-09s">
          <div class="team-leader-shadow">
            <a href="#"></a>
          </div>
          <img src="img/team-leader-pic3.jpg" alt="">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-twitter"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-pinterest"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-google-plus"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
            <h2 class="timer count-title" id="count-number" data-to="10" data-speed="1500"></h2>
            <p class="count-text ">points</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup" id="popup">
      <div class="popup__inner">
        <header class="popup__header">
          <a onclick="$('#popup').fadeOut()" id="popup-exit">esc</a>
        </header>
        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/124/124" alt="Bart Veneman" width="200" height="200" class="profile__image" />
        <section class="profile__details">
          <ul class="profile__stats">
            <li>
              <h3 class="profile_stat__heading">Gold</h3>
              <div class="profile_stat__number">17</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h3 class="profile_stat__heading">Silver</h3>
              <div class="profile_stat__number">8</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h3 class="profile_stat__heading">Bronze</h3>
              <div class="profile_stat__number">21</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <h2 class="profile__name" id="popup-name"></h2>
          <h2 class="profile__name">Designation: </h2>
          <h2 class="profile__name">Reporting Manager: </h2>
          <h2 class="profile__name">Email: </h2>
          <h2 class="profile__name">Date of Join: </h2>
          <h2 class="profile__name" id="popup-score"></h2>
          <h2 class="profile__name">Latest Week Points: </h2>
          <h2 class="profile__name">Overall Points: </h2>
          <h2 class="profile__name">Medals Rewarded:</h2>
          <ul class="social">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket"></i></a></li>
            <li class="location">
              <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
              <span>Bangalore, IN</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I think I am making some mistake with the JavaScript.

I just want to display the same popup on clicking  the points boxes as in pic above.

Comment: At line 550 (in your website page) you are opening a script tag inside at another script tag, leading to a javascript error and blocking the script execution. Try remove that part.
Open dev tools and inspect console errors for more details

Comment: $('.counter col_fourth a') is missing a dot before col_fourth and there's a space which doesn't have to be there; the big problem, though, is that you haven't any <a href...> element in your markup whic is descendant of .counter.coul_fourth...

Comment: @RDev Thanks for the input.I did what u said here.yet,no luck .

Comment: $('.counter col_fourth a') thats the class refering to the box.Space and dot ,i guess is not the issue here as the entire is the class name .Anyways ,thanks for the input @EmilianoCostanzo

Comment: unfortunately it is: to select an element which <div class="counter col_fourth"><a href="..."</a></div> you have to use $('.counter.col_fourth a').

the point is that both the selector in jquery is wrong and you have no <a...> element which descends from counter col fourth

Comment: I have voted to close this as off-topic, since it seems to rely on users needing to see the website. Our experience of external links is they break quickly, and once a problem is resolved it cannot be reviewed on the external website anyway. Since Stack Overflow is trying to collate useful Q&A for the long term, external links work against that goal. Please edit the question to remove the link, and put any further information in the question itself e.g. a JS Fiddle. Thanks.